# How can I focus() to another window on javascript, when the page loads?

Tags: javascript

## The new question

On Google Chrome, I can only `focus()` windows if an element has been clicked.

## The original question

*How can I `focus()` to a window using javascript, of which the popup window wasn't created inside the same window I'm using to focus the webpage*

```
var wnd = window.open("http://bing.co.uk", "stage");
```

Works fine for modifying popup windows that have been opened from a different webpage.

```
wnd.focus();
```

However this does not work as the stage window was already open, when the webpage with the wnd focus function was open.

Comment: Could you re-phrase that? Your intention is unclear.

Comment: Re your update: And your *question* is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer to your original question:

If you know that a window with that name exists, you can get a reference to it from a **later call** to `window.open` (e.g., when you want to call `blur` or `focus`):

```
window.open("", "theWindowName").focus();
```

But of course, if the window *doesn't* already exist, that will open a new window. Sadly, you can't know in advance (except in your application logic) whether a window with that name already exists.

Once you have the window object, you can call `blur` or `focus`.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/igepeh/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igepeh/1/edit)

---

#### Answer to your completely different, new question:

> On Google Chrome, I can only `focus()` windows if an element has been clicked.

If your code opened the window, you should be able to. For example:

HTML:

```
<button id="btnOpen">Open</button>
<button id="btnFocus">Focus</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#btnOpen").click(function() {
    window.open(
      "about:blank",
      "theWindow",
      "width=500,height=500");
  });
  $("#btnFocus").click(function() {
    // Note that this happens a full second later, NOT
    // in direct response to a user event
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open("", "theWindow").focus();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/igepeh/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igepeh/3/edit)

Comment: @desbest: No, you've completely *changed* it, which is not cool once you have answers. I've answered your new question.